# Django how to make model for user model

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I'm developing to-list app with registration . I have two models : Model for **User** and Model for **Tasks** . I add new task throw Ajax to **one** user it adding and displaying for **every** user. Is there any solutions ? Here **some pictures** 
[image: First user dashboard]

[image: Second user dashboard]

Here is my code:
**models.py**

```
 class Task(models.Model):
    title=models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    is_published=models.BooleanField(default=True)

 class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.FileField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/',null=True,blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
  if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['form_type'] == 'task':
    if request.is_ajax():
        addtask = AddTask(request.POST)
        if addtask.is_valid():
            user = request.user.id
            addtask.objects.filter(user=user).cleaned_data
            addtask.objects.filter(user=user).save()               
            task_object = Task.objects.filter(user=user)(addtask)
            return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'data': task_object})
        else:
            print(addtask.errors)
            return JsonResponse({'error': True, 'data': addtask.errors})
    else:
        error = {
            'message': 'Error, must be an Ajax call.'
        }
        return JsonResponse(error, content_type="application/json")



    addtask = AddTask()
    task = Task.objects.order_by('-date').filter(is_published=True)
```

**html page**

```
       {% if task %}
                    {% for tas in task %}
                Task content



                        {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}

                        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should add relation to CustomUser in Task model and filter tasks by owner in view before to render data to template?

```py
 class Task(models.Model):
    title=models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    is_published=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)

 class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.FileField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/',null=True,blank=True)
```

And in view:

```py
    ...
    addtask = AddTask()
    task = Task.objects.filter(is_published=True, user_id=request.user.id).order_by('-date')
```

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake is that you never connected your **CustomUser model** with your **Task model**. They should have a relationship like one to many. Once that is achieved, you have to retrieve only the tasks related to the **user of interest** from the database and send them to the HTML page. Then only the tasks related to one particular user will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to create CustomUser model, you should create a class and inherit it from **AbstractBaseUser** or **AbstractUser**([django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)).
2. Your Task model hasn't relationships with CustomUser. You create AddTask(?) instance but **didn't bind** it with any user.
3. You did not submit a view which renders HTML template, but I think that your query is something like `Tasks = Task.objects.all()` which return all tasks.

[This is how you should create CustomUser model](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/)

[This is documentation about relationships in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#relationships)

[This is about making queries in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)